# How to fix ChromeDriver SessionNotCreatedException in Google Colab?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I was asked to use a python web scraping script that was created in Google Colab, but I'm getting the following error:

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
> Current browser version is 117.0.5938.88 with binary path /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/117.0.5938.88/chrome

Am I correct in thinking that because Google Colab is a hosted coding platform that my local chromedriver version is irrelevant? How can I fix this?

If it helps, I believe this is the function causing the error...

```
def web_driver():
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--verbose")
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1200")
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  return driver
```

Comment: hi there - i also am having some issues with the selenium in colab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able use a different driver manager, [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), to get around the issue.

(`pip install seleniumbase`, and run with `python`)

Here's a simple example:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Here's your updated script, with the options you specified. Other options, (such as `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-gpu`), are already set by default.)

```
from seleniumbase import Driver

def web_driver():
    driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=True)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1200)
    return driver
```

Comment: it worked, as long as I installed jedi>=0.16. I'm hesitant to mark it as the correct answer though because the search returned no results. So I need to look into if there's a problem with the script itself or if it still has to do with the chromedriver.

Comment: @JonathanCakes I'd need to see more info to help debug that part. There's no search in your details.

Comment: so I think your bandaid works because I also downloaded the script locally and there's no chromedriver issue running locally. But the search is returning no results and I think it's a problem now with the XPATHs. For example, here's the XPATH for trying to get titles from Google search results: ".//div/div/div[1]/div/a/h3". I think Google must have changed the HTML structure since the time the script was written. I'm looking for the title, link and description, but maybe I should start a new question for that.

Comment: You can parse out those Google results from `div#center_col` (css selector).
Example test that checks Google results: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/boilerplates/samples/google_test.py